# "$python manage.py runserver" not working. Only "python3 manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have been working through the initial tutorial and ran into a load of issues with my anaconda install using python 2.7. In the end it wouldn't launch the server.

Anyway, I decided to change up on my machine to python3. That said, I am now getting strange results which are:

If I use the terminal command $python -m django --version I get the following:

"../Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named django"

If I change to "$python3 -m django --version" terminal gives me back: "1.11.4"

Now, when I am in the tutorial and starting again from the beginning I do the following: "$django-admin startproject mysite"

This seemed to work.

However, when I tried: "$python manage.py runserver" I get the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in 
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

If I change to include 3, so "$python3 manage.py runserver" all is well.

My question is do I need to always use python3 in every command now? I does not say that in the tutorial.

My Mac OSx has a native install of 2.7 which I believe is required by my machine for other apps dependency.

Any help would be really appreciated! I am sure given I am new to python I am being a complete moron!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install "virtualenv": https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/ and create virtual environment and install django there(which is good practice). You can avoid typing python3 inside virtual environment.

1. virtualenv --no-site-packages -p python3 venv
2. source venv/bin/activate
3. pip install django

   ..................

   ..................

python manage.py runserver

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I will do that! Just to check, will I need to reinstall python3 to that virtual machine or can I leave everything else where it is? I know SQLlite comes with the python download. Want to make sure all packages will be found.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Python 3's binaries are installed with a suffix of "3", so `python` will launch a Python 2 interpreter and you need to run `python3` to specifically use Python 3.

Comment: You might add that if you use a virtualenv you can just type python, regardless of it being 2 or 3. The Django Girls tutorial actually has [a note about it](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/#working-with-virtualenv).

Comment: That's great - I really appreciate the help!